# D3 Force directed graph with collapsible nodes - Remove animation/explosion

Tags: d3.js, collapsable, d3-force-directed

I am using the D3 force directed graph with collapsible nodes as described [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288)

Is there a way to avoid the explosion that happens when the graph is initially loaded? Also, can we stop the movement/animation of nodes once the graph has loaded?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't. I dumped this graph and I am now using collapsible tree graph.